# Hooks mapping array issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to render after the `useEffect` is done getting my info from my API, but I know that's incorrect.

I'm trying to come up with a good solution and I've nothing that works. I tried to make an if conditional render but it would not re-render once the users array was populated with the result from the API.

What am I missing or thinking about this incorrectly? the error is with the map function on the users,

> TypeError: users.map is not a function

(edit: sorry for the bad naming of "test" just trying to get it working not pretty at the moment, sorry if that irks you)

```js
const [users, changeUsers] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  async function test() {
    const response = await fetch('https://api');
    const json = await response.json();
    changeUsers(json);
  }
  test()
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    {
      users.map( (person) => {
        return <User test={person}/>
      })
    }
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Everything about your code looks fine. It most likely is related to the data you are receiving from your api. Are you sure it is an array? it might be an object with an array *inside*

Comment: the issue seems to be that the first time react renders everything the users is null so the map is not a function on the array of objects that the API returns. So it being null/empty the first time around because the useEffect wont run, until the component is rendered and build, is giving me issues.

Comment: You have initialised `users` to an empty array so it should be fine for the first render. Are you sure that your API returns an array? Check your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the response. Perhaps it's returning an object instead

Comment: I AM THE MOST OBLIVIOUS MAN ON THE EARTH! and I'm very ashamed to say yes Phil you were right it was an obj with an array of objects.....thank you